# Nearby place from my current location without using google maps api

Tags: android, android-studio, currentlocation

I would like to get the nearby place from my current location without using google maps api. Is it possible and how I could do it? I wrote the following code:

```
private float longitude[] = new float[2];
private float latitude[] = new float[2];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    latitude[0] = Float.parseFloat("37.79287000");
    longitude[0] = Float.parseFloat("26.70519000");

    latitude[1]=Float.parseFloat("40.65447000");
    longitude[1] = Float.parseFloat("22.95335000");

    for (int number = 0; number < 2; number++)
    {
        Location loc = null;
        Location.distanceBetween(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), latitude[],longitude[]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you still have to use an external database to have latitude and longitude of the places you want to show, doing it yourself is an enormous work.
I found this: https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database

Comment: Look into OpenStreetMaps.  But basically you're going to need some 3rd party that does what Google does.